# grab multiple data from multiple dictionaries having some conditions

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple dictionaries & i want to get the "oldest date" and the "name" of the branch that has the oldest date

I can get the oldest date using this but cannot get which branch has the oldest date.

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()

# objects


branch_1 = {
    "name": "b1",
    "gps": (48.8946865, 2.3622423),
    "oldestDate": dt.datetime(2019, 1, 7),
}

branch_2 = {
    "name": "b2",
    "gps": (48.839955, 2.288605),
    "cars": 7,
    "oldestDate": dt.datetime(2016, 1, 17),
}

branch_3 = {
    "name": "b3",
    "gps": (48.844244, 2.401435),
    "oldestDate": dt.datetime(2019, 1, 21),
```

}

```
listOBranches = [branch_1, branch_2, branch_3]
mtlst2 = []


def branchPriorityScore(listOBranches):
    for item in listOBranches:
        score = x - (item["oldestDate"])
        mtlst2.append(score)
        dateMax2 = np.max(mtlst2)
        name = item["name"]

    # return mtlst2
    print("Maximum Priority Branch : ", dateMax2)  # correct score
    # print("Maximum Priority Branch : ", np.max(mtlst2(item["name"])), dateMax2)


# mtlst2

branchPriorityScore(listOBranches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this.

```
def branchPriorityScore(listOBranches):
    oldest = datetime.timedelta()
    i = 0 #if you need index
    for index,item in enumerate(listOBranches):
        score = x - (item["oldestDate"])
        if score > oldest:
            oldest = score
            i = index #if you need index
            name = item["name"]


    print (name,i,oldest,listOBranches[i]['oldestDate'])
```

No sure why you need mtlst2 but you can add it in the cycle too.

Comment: Hey Mur4al, Thanks! your solution worked. Could you tell me how to advance on if i want to get a list with all branches with their priorities ?

Comment: Do you want a list with branches sorted from oldest to newest?

Comment: You can use a sort method with lambda as a key.`listOBranches.sort(key = lambda i:x-i["oldestDate"],reverse = True)` If you dont mind changing original list. Or `sorted(listOBranches,key = lambda i:x-i["oldestDate"],reverse = True)` to create new one.